# How can I change background colour of a button on key press?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I've been working on JavaScript on-screen keyboard kind of thing, just for experimentation. I wanted to see if I could detect which key had been pressed, and make the corresponding on-screen keyboard button change colour, similar to many online touch typing courses have. 
I have tried many variations of the `onkeydown` command, but no luck.

```
//doesn't seem to do anything.
document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor="#004f40";
```

Button's id is simply it's value eg/ the A key is `id="a"`.

Could anyone give me any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/onclick-in-css

Comment: put your code here or use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Maybe I went a bit too far, but I like onscreen keyboards so made a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3aQZG/. I strongly suggest using jQuery in your case (can articulate if the demo fulfills your needs). The keyboard is a bit long, but at the end of it you have the input to catch keydon / up events (fiddle catches those events on body so had to use a target input field).

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your problem? If you did, consider sharing it with us.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that sets the color first in CSS and uses javascript [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) to listen for a click [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) and changes the color of the button when clicked, it also removes the attached event listener.

CSS

```
#a {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="a">My Button</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", function onClick() {
    this.removeEventListener("click", onClick);

    this.style.backgroundColor = "#004f40";  
}, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/CKUCW/)

This example uses the mouse [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick) event, but you will need to look at [key events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent) instead of a mouse one, it could be one of many; e.g. [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/keydown), [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/keypress), or [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/keyup).

**Update**: Here is one possible solution using key events.

CSS

```
button {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Javascript

```
var start = 97,
    end = 122,
    button;

while (start <= end) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = button.textContent = String.fromCharCode(start);
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    start += 1;
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", function onKeypress(evt) {
    var element = document.getElementById(String.fromCharCode(evt.charCode || evt.char));

    if (element) {
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function onKeyup() {
            document.removeEventListener("keyup", onKeyup);

            element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }, false);

        element.style.backgroundColor = "#004f40";
    }
}, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Mqyn9/)

Note: this example is by no means perfect, it it just an example of how to use events.

**Update**: here is another example that uses all 3 events to de-bounce the keyboard when multiple keys are pressed and released. (Compare it in use with above.)

CSS

```
button {
    background-color: yellow;
}
button:active {
    background-color: #004f40;
}
```

Javascript

```
var start = 97,
    end = 122,
    button;

while (start <= end) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = button.textContent = String.fromCharCode(start);
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    start += 1;
}

var keydown,
    keypress = [];

document.addEventListener("keydown", function onKeydown(e1) {
    keydown = e1;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("keypress", function onKeypress(e2) {
    var record = {
        "char": e2.char || e2.charCode,
            "key": keydown.key || keydown.keyCode || keyDown.which,
            "shiftKey": keydown.shiftKey,
            "metaKey": keydown.metaKey,
            "altKey": keydown.altKey,
            "ctrlKey": keydown.ctrlKey
    },
    element = document.getElementById(String.fromCharCode(e2.charCode || e2.char));

    if (element) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#004f40";
        keypress.push(record);
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("keyup", function onKeyup(e3) {
    var key = e3.key || e3.keyCode || e3.which;

    keypress.forEach(function (record) {
        if (record.key === key && record.shiftKey === e3.shiftKey && record.metaKey === e3.metaKey && record.altKey === e3.altKey && record.ctrlKey === e3.ctrlKey) {
            document.getElementById(String.fromCharCode(record.char)).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
    });
}, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/48dgL/)

Note: even this is not perfect as it depends on millisecond timing to match keydown and keypress events.

Answer (score -1):

Or alternatively, you could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
    $(".keyboardButton").mousedown(function(){
      $(this).css("background":"#Color-when-pressed");
    }

    $(".keyboardButton").mouseup(function(){
      $(this).css("background":"#Color-when-released");
    }
```

Of course, replace the colors respectively.
[Get jQuery](http://jquery.com/download)

Or pure CSS:

```
   .keyboardButton:active {
     background:#Color-when-pressed;
   }
   .keyboardButton {
     background:#Color-when-released;
   }
```

It might be the best, since you won't have to write code for every single button you have, and you probably already have CSS classes for them.

Comment: I forked sixFingers' fiddle to use the pure CSS method above:
http://jsfiddle.net/JFnKp/

Comment: Your jquery example should be using ´keydown´ and ´keyup´: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/ It also has a syntax error as the ":" after "background" should be a ",". Finally with this fixed, your example has the same key bounce issue as my second example. Also, your CSS example only works on mouse clicks and not key presses.