# html how to animate a comment form

Tags: html, css, animation

I have written this html:

```
 <a href="#" class="addcomment">Add Comment</a>
<div id="addcomment">
<form name="comment" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="addcomment" size="80" />
<input type="submit" value="Comment">
</form>
```

What I want is when I click the "Add comment" then form should be displayed in place of "*Add comment*" just like on "*stackoverflow*". How can I make this happen??

Comment: Have you looked at Javascript at all? This is not doable with just HTML and CSS.

Comment: could you show your attempts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [onclick in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/onclick-in-css) look the answer of @Hendra Uzia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty proof, optimize from here:

CSS:

```
#addcomment {
    display : none;
}
.addcomment:active {
    display : none;
}
.addcomment:active + #addcomment {
    display : block;
    position : absolute;
    top : 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7uax74qd/

Comment: I tried this and it worked but when I click add comment it appears and when I release it disappear.. whats the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for it...

```
 <a href="#" id="add" class="addcomment" onclick="show()">Add Comment</a>
<div id="addcomment" style="display:none;">
<form name="comment" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="addcomment" size="80" />
<input type="submit" value="Comment">
</form>
```

THEN IN JAVASCRIPT write a function and call that in anchor tag..

```
function show()
{
document.getElementById('add').style.display='none';
document.getElementByid('addcomment').style.display='block';
}
```