# How do i make a drop down box like this one without jquery?(example inside)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here's an example of what i'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxXt8.jpg)

I can't use jquery, can i do this with just pure js and css?

thanks :)

Comment: This isn't going to be easy but this may point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17257848/4270597  What are your reasons for not using JQuery?

Comment: jQuery is "just"a library (a damn good one) writen in JS and in theory you can do anything just with JS  but before anything else please read it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been better if you can provide some code.
You can check below codepen code. I have implemented it on CSS hover no js is involved. Check if it helps.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="next">

  </div>
</div>

.main{
  min-height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  transition:all 0.8s ease-out;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.next{
  height:0px;
  background-color:green;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-out
}
.main:hover{
  padding-top:50px;
}
.main:hover .next{
  height:50px;

}
```

http://codepen.io/gauravshankar/pen/ZYjZEd

This can also be done on click if you use a checkbox or a radio button.

Comment: thanks, i changed your code a bit and now it's fine :), how can i make it happen only when you click the div?

Answer (score 1):

You should add some code, i'll add some when you do :)

You'll want to use css animations and have the div use a default state of `display:none, height: 0;`

Then with JS you can add hide the class. This class will `display:block, height: 50px`

Comment: I have an array with all the items from the data base, so i want to print these divs for every one. im printing them with a for loop in jsp. I edited my post the code is in there.