# Display a form when clicking on an anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/onclick-in-css) but to a `table`- instead of a `div`-tag.

If I use `:active` it doesn't display the table when I click on the anchor and when I use `:target` it shows the table before clicking on the anchor.

Here's my code:

```
<table id="addForm">
    <tr><td class="label">Address:</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Type of Toilet:</td>
        <td>    
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked>Male
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Both">Both
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Review:</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class="label">Rating:</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#addForm {
    display:none;
}

#addForm:active{
    display:block;
    font-style:Sans-serif;
    width:320;
    font-size:12;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Why would clicking on an anchor make the form active? `#addForm:active` happens when you click on the form itself, not some unrelated element. But you can't click on the form if it's not visible.

Comment: @Dmitriy is right - where do you place the opening <form>?

Comment: Ya but its not working @Amit

Comment: Yaa!! @Amit your answer was right. It was some script problems. Thank You!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should be using JavaScript to handle this functionality. That being said you can do this by targeting an element that has an ID with your anchor like this:

## Method 1: Pure CSS

```css
#addForm {
  display: none;
}
#addForm:target {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<a href="#addForm">Show</a>

<table id="addForm">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Address:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Type of Toilet:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked />Male
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" />Female
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Both" />Both</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Review:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Rating:</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

## Method 2: JavaScript Toggle

A better way all around would be to use JavaScript like this:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#showForm").on("click", function() {

    $("#addForm").toggle();

  });

});
```

```css
#addForm {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="showForm">Test</a>

<table id="addForm">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Address:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Type of Toilet:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked />Male
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" />Female
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Both" />Both</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Review:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Rating:</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you.. That javascript worked. Even [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qaa1bqrk/) also worked.

Comment: The toggle() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

`:active` only works when the mouse is pressed down. The way it would work is to apply it to a parent of the table like below, although it won't work for what you're wanting it to do.

```css
#addForm {
  display: none;
}
#addFormContainer:active #addForm {
  display: table;
}
#addFormContainer:active p {
  display: none;
}
#addFormContainer p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="addFormContainer">
  <p>Click to load form</p>
  <table id="addForm">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Address:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Type of Toilet:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked>Male
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Both">Both
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Review:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Rating:</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Perhaps it might be better for you to use `:hover` instead:

```css
#addForm {
  display: none;
}
#addFormContainer:hover #addForm {
  display: table;
}
#addFormContainer:hover p {
  display: none;
}
#addFormContainer p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="addFormContainer">
  <p>Hover to load form</p>
  <table id="addForm">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Address:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Type of Toilet:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked>Male
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Both">Both
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Review:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Rating:</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a bad user experience, you should not remove the "hover to load form" text.

Comment: Uhm, you do realise this is just an example right? Besides, that's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some CSS examples for you which is pretty much the best you are going to get:

Firstly notice my HTML structure, the only way you are going to get this to work is to next your `table` inside your anchor tag, this is poor HTML.

Using `:active` to show the form, this shows the form when you click but there is nothing to keep the form displaying, so you have to hold the click down meaning you can't use the form. (this is explained in the question you link to).
https://jsfiddle.net/yLcq3ohq/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="reveal form" >Reveal Form

    <table id="addForm">
        <tr><td class="label">Address:</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Type of Toilet:</td>
            <td>    
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked>Male
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Both">Both
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Review:</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="label">Rating:</td></tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

CSS:
    a {
        height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

```
a:active {
    height: auto;
}
```

This second option is again using poorly formed HTML and `:hover` this allows your to use the form but it will only be displayed while you hover over it.
https://jsfiddle.net/yLcq3ohq/1/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="reveal form" >Reveal Form

    <table id="addForm">
        <tr><td class="label">Address:</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Type of Toilet:</td>
            <td>    
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked>Male
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Both">Both
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Review:</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="label">Rating:</td></tr>
    </table>
</a>

a {
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

CSS:

```
a:hover {
    height: auto;
}
```

From what I can see you cannot achieve what you want to do without JavaScript.

Comment: You don't need to nest it inside an anchor. Also posting Fiddle links without posting your code makes you a bad person. If JSFiddle disappeared off the internet your post becomes useless.

Comment: This entirely depends on his HTML structure, it is possible to select a sibling element but it's it not greatly supported. You can't select parents so the best choice for support is to make it a child element.

Comment: The only browser that `:active` will only work with an anchor is IE7. I hope that in 2015 we are not trying to target this browser still?

Comment: Fair comment about the code I have added that in. In regards to browser support you misread my comment, I was talking about the `~` or `+` sibling selector, which is actually supported better than I thought but there is issues with comments, something to be aware of. Also if you read the question, the asker specifically asks to click on a link and show a form, this is what I have done, I don't think there is grounds to down vote me.

Comment: I down-voted for the lack of code in the answer. I agree the way he worded it was that he was clicking a link, but then the code he supplied suggested that the table was going to be clicked. Some people aren't able to supply the correct terminology for things so you have to read between the lines and not take things in a literal sense with some people.

Comment: Not a problem. As it happens, Chris Spittles answer is better than both of ours combined ;)