# write text in input with click on label/etc (html only)

Tags: html, input, insert, click, label

I want to know if there is a pure html solution that when I click on a label or something a prefefined text is inserted in the text input field.

I know this would be easy with javascript/jquery but I think maybe there could be a pure html solution for this.

Comment: No, there isn't. HTML is a purely passive content markup.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use pseudo css selectors.

You can refer [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/onclick-in-css)