# How to collapse navbar content for medium size screen using bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have created a navbar using bootstrap 4 alpha, and would like to hide the content of the navbar with a ☰ (hamburger menu) when the site / page is viewed on a medium size screen.

As of right now, both the ☰ (hamburger menu) and the navbar content are displaying when I load the page with a medium size browser window.
[image: issue with navbar]

Ideally, I would like to hide the navbar list items when the page loads, and just display the hamburger menu, and then display the list items once the hamburger menu is clicked.  If it is clicked again, I would like to hide the items.

The code in question looks like the following,
**_nav.html.erb**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-down" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content">
    ☰
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="nav-content">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://example.io">example.io</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

<% if user_signed_in? %>

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"<%= link_to current_user.email, edit_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
    <% else %>

    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"<%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path%>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"<%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %>
    </li>

    <% end %>


    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"<%= link_to "About", about_path %></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link"<%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Uplodad Image</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
  <form class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Since you want three different states with regard to the hamburger menu, you'll need JavaScript to accomplish this. If it were just two, you could get away with using a [checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32721572/2756409) hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes to `_nav.html.erb` solved my issue.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content">
    ☰ example.io
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="nav-content">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://example.io">example.io</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

Answer (score 0):

just give class `navbar-expand-xl` to the nav container

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.