# CSS stay in that position on click

Tags: css

I need to do this in only `CSS` not in `jQuery`, is there a way that, when I click on a div I can say in `CSS` that a other div have to be `display: block;`?

I only used `:active`, but it wasn't what I needed, so I hope you guys know an other way to do this :)

**PS: NOT IN jQuery!**

Code:

```
.dropdown-submenu:active > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

Comment: Ye I saw this post, but I could't use it. its just like the sub-menu have to displayed also when mouse is up not only on mousedown.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Checkbox trick**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle">Click me!</label>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Contain</p>


.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**The Focus way:**

```
<span tabindex="0">Click button</span>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Contain</p>

span:focus ~ .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

You can hide the checkbox using position or display none.
See more detail with demos here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/

Comment: I not realy get the way of checkbox :s

Comment: Lenap, I edited. The idea is when you click on label, it turns the checkbox on/off.