# Is there a way that i can have a onclick in css?

Tags: html, css

Is there a `:hover` selector that can be used when an 'a' tag is clicked it causes it to change color and then turns back when the click is released?

Any help is much appreciated. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

Use `:active` selector, this is used to select the active element, in this case the `a` element.

```css
a:active{
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<a>Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one too

`https://jsfiddle.net/kLju23fx/2/`

```
<code>
a:hover {
    color: hotpink;
}
a:active {
    color: blue;
}
a:link {
    color: red;
}
a:visited {
    color: green;
}
</code>
```