# Is it possible to create custom CSS pseudo-classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am thinking of an alternative to JavaScript in case it's manually disabled by the user, so that instead of prompting them to enabled it, I could, for instance, in some way simulate the click event and change, for instance, the background colour by creating my own :click pseudo-class, just like it works for :hover.

Is such a scenario possible? Is it possible for one to create their own css pseudo-classes that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question is, can I create a custom pseudo, example;

```css
div:my-custom-pseudo { }
```

Then not without some JavaScript libraries.

[Tutorial on using it with mooTools and slick](https://davidwalsh.name/slick-pseudo)

Personally, I haven't used this, so I don't know browser support and this is pretty much the only resource I ever found on custom pseudo classes.

**Edit:**

So pretty much, no, you can't do what you want, as you will always need JavaScript to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mark. I am going to check it out.

Comment: Some solution in `vanilla JS` without `moTools` or `jQuery`?

Answer (score 4):

Creating pseudo-classes is not possible and if you can simulate that also on some browser, then it would likely not work on others.

For that simple reason, all `:first-child` and `:last-child` polyfills/fallbacks were done by using class names rather than trying to make pseudo-class work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @David.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:active` pseudo class. If I understand you properly.

Comment: The :active pseudo-class requires that an element be held. This does not simulate the click event. My question is if it is possible to create a pseudo-class, not use an existing one.

Comment: Ok, now i understand you. You can make pseudo classes only with JavaScript library, but in your case it's disabled.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom State Pseudo Classes](https://wicg.github.io/custom-state-pseudo-class/) may indeed be available in the future (for Custom Elements).