# Zoom in and out on mouse click with CSS

Tags: css

I want to zoom image with only CSS. The code below zooms the image when the left button of the mouse is kept pressed but I want to zoom in and out with a mouse click. How can I achieve that?

```
.container img {
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

.container img:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

Comment: bunch of interesting answers here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Let's use a trick here, an input checkbox:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.container img {
  margin: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label > img {
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="zoomCheck">
  <label for="zoomCheck">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: That is pretty neato

Comment: you can use the margin 200px or 2x margin in `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label > img` instead putting it on `.container img` directly , so it will not break your own css

Answer (score 18):

Building on @Nhan answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39859268/661872

Shorter, scoped and does not require tracking ids for multiple elements.

```css
.click-zoom input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}

.click-zoom img {
  margin: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in
}

.click-zoom input[type=checkbox]:checked~img {
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out
}
```

```html
<div class="click-zoom">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  </label>
</div>

<div class="click-zoom">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the neatest trick I've stumbled on for a long time. You can even set the img tag width as you see fit and it still works like a charm. A real keeper, doing so much with so little code. Hats off !

Comment: Great solution. This should be the accepted one as that one does not really work. With the accepted one, clicking on another different image on same page, magnifies the same image each time!  But your solution magnifies the correct image each time.

Comment: fyi, added question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401777/click-to-enlarge-image-then-click-again-to-make-it-go-back-to-previous-size and referenced your answer. May be you know a solution.

Comment: @Nasser not sure what you mean, thanks though ;p To do in js like https://jsbin.com/cixokozano/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 3):

## 4 Ways to Add *Click Events* with Only CSS Pseudo-Selectors

**Note:** I'll be using the word *target* when referring to the element we want to manipulate and *trigger* as the element we are using to manipulate *target*.

### `:checked`

Use checkboxes or radios and `:checked` to determine or cause a *target's* state and/or to take action.

**Trigger**

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox">
 <!--or--> 
<input type="radio">
```

**Conditions**

- Requires that the *target* must be:

  - A sibling that follows the *trigger* or...
  - ...a descendant of the *trigger*.

**Note**

- Hide the actual `<checkbox>` with `display:none`
- Ensure that the `<checkbox>` has an `id` and that the `<label>` has a `for` attribute with a value matching the `id` of the `<checkbox>`
- This is dependant upon the *target* being a sibling that follows the *trigger* or the *target* as a descendant. Therefore be aware that you'll most likely use  these selector combinators: `~`, `+`, `>`.

**HTML**

```
<label for='chx'>CHX</label>
<input id='chx' type="checkbox">

<div>TARGET</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#chx:checked + div {...
```

---

### `:target`

Use an `<a>`nchor and apply the `:target` pseudo-selector on the target element.

**Trigger**

```
<a href=""></a>
```

**Conditions**

- Assign an `id` to the target.
- Assign that same `id` to the `<a>` `href` attribute preceding with a hash `#`

**HTML**

```
<a href='#target'>A</a>

<div id='target'>TARGET</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#target:target {...
```

---

### `:focus`

The *trigger* element must be either an `<input>` type ***or*** have the attribute `tabindex` in order to use `:focus`.

**Trigger**

```
<div tabindex='0'>ANY INPUT OR USE TABINDEX</div>
```

**Conditions**

- *Target* must a sibling that is located after the *trigger* or *target must be a descendant of the *trigger*.
- State or effect will persist until user clicks elsewhere thereafter a `blur` or `unfocus` event will occur.

**HTML**

```
<nav tabindex='0'>
  <a href='#/'>TARGET</a>
  <a href='#/'>TARGET</a>
  <a href='#/'>TARGET</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
 nav:focus ~ a {...
```

---

`:active`
-

This is a hack that cleverly exploits the `transition-delay` property in order to actually have a persistent state achieved with no script.

**Trigger**

```
<a href='#/'>A</a>
```

**Conditions**

- *Target* must a sibling that is located after the *trigger* or *target must be a descendant of the *trigger*.
- There must be a `transition` assigned to the *target* twice.

  - The first one to represent the persistent state.
  - The second one to represent the normal state.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#/">A</a>

<div class='target'>TARGET</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.target {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0s 9999999s;
 }

 a:active ~ .target {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 0s;
 }
```

Wacked looking, right? Under normal circumstances, if your *trigger* had the `:active` pseudo-selector, we are able to manipulate the *target* upon *keydown*. That means our active state is actually active as long as you keep your finger on the button...that's crappy and useless, I mean what are you expected to do to make `.active` to be useful? Maybe a paperweight and some rubber bands to keep a steady and persistent pressure on the button?

We will leave `.active` the way it is: lame and useless. Instead:

1. Make a ruleset for *target* under normal circumstances. In the example above it's `opacity:1`.
2. Next we add a `transition:` ...ok then... `all` which works, next is `0s` ...ok so this *transition* isn't going to be seen it's duration is 0 seconds, and finally...  `9999999s` ...116 days delay?
   We'll come back to that, we will continue onto the next rulesets...
3. These rulesets declare what happens to *target* under the influence of *trigger:active*. As you can see that it just does what it normally does, which is onkeydown *target* will become invisible in 0 seconds. Now once the user keys up, *target* is visible again...no *target's * new state of `opacity:0` is persistent! No paperweight, technology has come a long way.
4. The *target* is still actually going to revert back to it's normal state, because `:active` is too lazy and feeble to work without rubber bands and paperweights. The persistent state is perceived and not real because *target* is still leaving the state brought on by `:active` which will be about 116 days before that will happen. ;)

---

This Snippet features the 4 ways previously mentioned. I'm aware that the OP requested zoom (which is featured therein), but thought it would be to repetitive and boring, so I added different effects as well as zooming.

###SNIPPET

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display:inline-block;
}
button {
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: grey;
  font:inherit;
  display:inline-block;
}
img#img {
  width: 384px;
  height: 384px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transition: width 3s height 3s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 99999999s;
}
#zoomIn,
#zoomOut,
#spin {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#zoomOut:checked + img#img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
}
#zoomIn:checked + img#img {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
  
#spin:checked ~ img#img {
  transform: rotate(1440deg);
}
img#img:target {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 6px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
a.out:focus ~ img#img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
a.in:active ~ img#img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.grey:focus ~ img#img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<a href='#/' class='out'>FadeouT</a><a href='#/' class='in'>FadeiN</a>

<a href='#img'>ShadoW</a>

<br/><button class='grey' tabindex='0'>GreyscalE</button><br/>

<label for='spin'>SpiN</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='spin'>

<label for='zoomIn'>ZoomiN</label>
<input type='radio' id='zoomIn' name='zoom'>

<label for='zoomOut'>ZoomouT</label>
<input type='radio' id='zoomOut' name='zoom'>

<img id='img' src='https://i.ibb.co/5LPXSfn/Lenna-test-image.png'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
   <head>
      <title>Image Zoom</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         #imagediv {
         margin:0 auto;
         height:400px;
         width:400px;
         overflow:hidden;
         }
         img {
         position: relative;
         left: 50%;
         top: 50%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="button" value ="-" onclick="zoom(0.9)"/>
      <input type="button" value ="+" onclick="zoom(1.1)"/>
      <div id="imagediv">
         <img id="pic" src=""/>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         window.onload = function(){zoom(1)}
         function zoom(zm) {
             img=document.getElementById("pic")
             wid=img.width
             ht=img.height
             img.style.width=(wid*zm)+"px"
             img.style.height=(ht*zm)+"px"
             img.style.marginLeft = -(img.width/2) + "px";
             img.style.marginTop = -(img.height/2) + "px";
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gajal try to explain your answer in more detail rather than just posting the code. Please also indicate what you have changed or added.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container img {
  margin: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label > img {
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="zoomCheck">
  <label for="zoomCheck">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish there was some explanation for what the code is doing. But this seems like the most elegant approach.