# Click to enlarge image, then click again to make it go back to previous size

Tags: javascript, html, class, if-statement

I want to be able to click on an image, have it become big, and then when I click it again, make it go back to being small.  I'm trying to use an if/else statement to solve this problem, but I still can't figure it out.  This is the JS I have so far:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
 var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

 if (thumbnailElement.className === "small") {
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
     thumbnailElement.className = "";
    });
 } else {
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
     thumbnailElement.className = "small";
    });
 }
});
```

And the HTML for the image:

```
<img class="small" id="smart_thumbnail" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-QFiV4z\
3gloQ/ULd1wyJb1oI/AAAAAAAAEIg/LE1Kakhve9Y/s1600/Hieroglyphs_Ani-papyrus.jpg">
```

I'm simply wanting to get rid of the "small" class on the id "smart_thumbnail" to make it big and put the "small" class back to make it small again, but I can only make it big.  When I click on it the 2nd time, it doesn't do anything.  I've tried an if/else if statement and that didn't work.  I looked on here for the same question, but could only find stuff about jQuery.  Trying to solve this with JavaScript only.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you checking the className in `DOMContentLoaded`, before it can possibly change?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods

Comment: Ohhhh, okay.  Sorry, I'm still new.  This is part of a bootcamp application process and that first line of code is something they said to include in all the JS we do.

Comment: That's a bad bootcamp; they should explain what every line means.

Comment: Yeah, you're telling me...I feel so betrayed by them!  Haha.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code above will only be run once: After loading your site. So only one condition is fullfilled (`thumbnailElement.className === "small"`)

What you want is something along the lines of:

```
var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.className === "small")
    this.className = "";
  else
    this.className = "small";
});
```

This will check the class when clicking the image.

Alternatively, you can also use [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event only fires once, that is, when the page is loaded. Instead run your if-statement on a per-click basis.

For example

```
thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (thumbnailElement.className === "small") {
      thumbnailElement.className = "";
  } else {
     thumbnailElement.className = "small";
  }
});
```

Now you will register the click event once, but every time it is clicked it will check the classname logic and apply the class name appropriately.