# Html CSS put fireworks images animated not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, fireworks

I put the html css fireworks image on the image zoom animated effect (like a fireworks ), but its not working, any solution for this

Thanks

```css
.slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  right: 25%;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: zoomIn 3000ms infinite ease;
  -webkit-animation: zoomIn 3000ms infinite ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
    0% {transform: scale(1);}
    50% {transform: scale(1.5);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<span class="slide2" style="transform: matrix3d(0.7167, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7167, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7167, 0, -14.9212, 4.5442, 0, 1);"><img src="http://brotherslab.thesoftking.com/html/lotten/demo/assets/images/shape/star.png" alt="banner-shape"></span>
```

Comment: Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858998/zoom-in-and-out-on-mouse-click-with-css

Comment: you haven't used keyframe

Comment: @RevtiShah Hi, yes, i added  the keyframe like this ` @-webkit-keyframes slide1  {
    0% {transform: scale(1);}
    50% {transform: scale(1.5);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
},  ` not working

Comment: @core114 add to your question

Comment: Please follow this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/27Syr/1206/

Comment: Your animation is called slide2, but your trying to call one called zoomIn.