# click image to enlarge to specific size, click again brings it back to original size. No scaling but using exact image size

Tags: html, css, image

There are number of questions on how to enlarge an image on a click, and then clicking again on the now enlarged images, brings back down to its original size.

For the last 10 hrs, I have been trying many of them, and none of them do what I want.

I have found one solution below which does this, except it uses scale.

The problem is that it uses CSS transform, which scales the original image size by some factor.

Instead of scaling, I want to make the enlarged image be of specific width. Say `800px` regardless of the original image size.

Scaling does not work well. If the original image was small, say 100px, then scaling by say 2, it is still small to see. And if the original image was large, scaling by 2 will now make it too large. Since I want to use this code for all my images and they are all of different sizes, this will not work.

The code below is working, except I want help to change it from using scaling by 2 to do this instead: make the enlarged image of width 800px, and I do not know how to do this. CSS transform only takes scaling as far as I could find out.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head>

<STYLE>
body{/* for illustration only*/
 margin:  0 auto;  /* center */
 margin-top:200px;
 max-width: 640px; 
}

/* below taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401601/765271*/

.click-zoom input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}

.click-zoom img {  
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in
}

.click-zoom input[type=checkbox]:checked~img {
  /* how to modify this to use exact image width instead of scaling?*/
  transform:  scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out
}
</STYLE> 
</head><body>

<div class='click-zoom'> 
  <label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
          <img src='https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1450272068/photo/wind-sun-and-water-energy.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=zmMsbQLf_RcuaKVH4coGYzZuFnD5FFUtTNAEo6yUO8o=' width="200">
  </label>
</div> 

<div class='click-zoom'> 
  <label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
          <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_1280.jpg' width="200">
  </label>
</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Feel free to change the image src above. I did not know what internet image to use.

Link to CSS scale

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Here is a demo of the above on my PC

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head>

<STYLE>
body{/* for illustration only*/
 margin:  0 auto;  /* center */
 margin-top:200px;
 max-width: 640px; 
}

/* below taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401601/765271*/

.click-zoom input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}

.click-zoom img {  
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in
}

.click-zoom input[type=checkbox]:checked~img {
  transform:  scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out
}
</STYLE> 
</head><body>

<div class='click-zoom'> 
  <label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
          <img src='https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1450272068/photo/wind-sun-and-water-energy.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=zmMsbQLf_RcuaKVH4coGYzZuFnD5FFUtTNAEo6yUO8o=' width="200">
  </label>
</div> 

<div class='click-zoom'> 
  <label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
          <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_1280.jpg' width="200">
  </label>
</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Making your code into a runnable snippet will make it easier for us to debug. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth added two images from the internet I found. The code is all self contained and runs as is.

Comment: Yes, but I’m on an iOS system so cannot create a snippet unless you create one first!

Comment: @AHaworth I do not understand what you mean. I posted the full HTML code in my question. What else should I do?  I do not have account at fiddler or codepen or any such web sites. Any one can run this by just copying the code to their PC and run it.  If you know how to make it runnable  inside this forum, feel free to do this. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: @AHaworth I finally figure it out. Added code snippet. First time doing this.

Comment: Why not transition width rather than scale? Is there a reason you use the width attribute rather than CSS?

Comment: @AHaworth I do not understand what you mean. I am not very skilled in CSS and HTML. I used a solution that I found and works. I just do not want to use scale() to enlarge the image, I want to use exact `width:800px` instead. I do not know how to do this. If you know, feel free to give an answer.

Comment: What about displaying the image in a [lightbox](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)?

Comment: I was wondering why you used the HTML attribute width: 200px rather than CSS width: 200px.

Comment: @AHaworth oh, that is just an example. It does not really matter for the purpose of the question. I wanted to make it simple, that is all. Using CSS will be better, yes.

Comment: @BrettDonald I looked at lightbox, but all the examples shown seem to use what is called modal image, and enlarge the image over the whole page, .ie. making what looks like a new window on top. I do not want that. I want the same as I showed in my example. But if you know of a way using lightbox to produce same result I show, please feel free to answer. I never used lightbox myself, just looked at their demos.

Comment: Where do you want the expanded image to be in relation to the viewport? And I guess you are aware a 100px image at 800px will look pretty fuzzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to calculate the scale.

In this snippet, I have chosen to zoom to 500px instead of 800px because it fits the snippet window better. My images are all displayed smaller than 500px, then will scale to 500px when clicked. Note also that two of them are low-res images, which look quite pixellated when scaled, whereas two of them are high-res images, displayed smaller, which look crisp when scaled. After you run the snippet, use the **full page** link for the full effect.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    if (i.classList.contains('zoomed'))
      i.style.transform = ''
    else {
      const myScale = 500 / i.clientWidth
      i.style.transform = `scale(${myScale})`
    }
    i.classList.toggle('zoomed')
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
}

p:has(.ruler) {
  background: red;
}

.ruler {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {  
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}


img.zoomed {
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="ruler">this orange bar is 500px wide</span></p>
<p><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/140/300/200'></p>
<p><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/140/1000/667' style="width: 200px;"></p>
<p><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/144/300/200'></p>
<p><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/144/1000/667' style="width: 200px;"></p>
<p><span class="ruler">this orange bar is 500px wide</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code given works perfectly.

To demonstrate this I have replaced one of the images with one whose natural dimensions are 100x300.

Initially it shows at 200px wide and 600px high due to the HTML width attribute being set at 200.

Now when things are scaled it is this width that is scaled by 2, not the natural width of the image.

Of course the image looks fuzzy and this is to be expected when you make a low quality image be displayed at a width/height beyond its natural dimensions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'>

<head>

  <STYLE>
    body {
      /* for illustration only*/
      margin: 0 auto;
      /* center */
      margin-top: 200px;
      max-width: 640px;
    }
    /* below taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401601/765271*/
    
    .click-zoom input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none
    }
    
    .click-zoom img {
      transition: transform 0.25s ease;
      cursor: zoom-in
    }
    
    .click-zoom input[type=checkbox]:checked~img {
      transform: scale(2);
      cursor: zoom-out
    }
  </STYLE>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='click-zoom'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
          <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100/300' width="200">
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class='click-zoom'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
          <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_1280.jpg' width="200">
  </label>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```