# CSS focus not working

Tags: css

In the link above, how can I make that when I click on "Register" it will hide the welcome class and show the register class ...
If I substitute focus for hover it works but it's obvious that I need a clickable option and not on mouse over...

```
*:hover ~ .register_box {
  display: flex;
}

*:hover ~ .welcome_box {
  display: none;
}
```

And I am wondering  how to do this in CSS not JavaScript.

And I am using all elements selection (the "*") for testing purpose.

https://jsfiddle.net/sufwaqaa/

Comment: Check this question and its answers, you may find some solutions for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css

Comment: Like i said, i would like a clickable option in CSS. The active event is not a permanent option cause it will only work while i am clicking on the element.

Comment: Maybe the checkbox option (that is explained in the link that Mattia gave the 88 answer) is a way of doing it. But why does the focus does not work ? isn't the focus for this type of things ?

Comment: Well, no. _":focus selector is allowed on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs."_

You can't just focus a div. To do stuff like this you have to go with javascript or try some workarounds, like the label/radio-button

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: Check also this tutorial, it explain really well the potential of the label/radiobutton tecnique: https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/

Comment: `~` represents sibling element. The `.register_box` and `.welcome_box` are not siblings to the register or welcome elements.

Comment: With checkbox it oes not work has well... maybe it's cause the same sibling thing has with focus... with hover it works... guess that it's only possible with js