# How to centre Hamburger CSS, centre text and add border

Tags: html, css

I have been trying and trying to achieve 3 things with a Hamburger menu but to no avail. This is a responsive Hamburger that changes to a X on click and moves to the right of the page with transition (all of which works fine although with the shortened code wont in the Fiddle).

1) I would like to vertically centre the Hamburger menu within the Nav Bar with Menu text at the side but also have this text vertically centred (so it appears halfway up the Hamburger). I can vertically centre the Hamburger menu okay but once I add text the text is always in line with the bottom of the Hamburger lines.

2) In addition I would also like a border around the entire Hamburger itself, with padding, and then the text at the side outside of this. Whatever I try it just puts a border around the actual Hamburger lines or the entire Hamburger with no padding.

3) Also is there a way to changes the colour of both the Hamburger and text on hover and click? The best I've achieved is changing the colour of the text but not the Hamburger. I have searched and searched but cannot find anything that works.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/usLvjp48/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#toggle-nav').click(function (e) {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.hamburgerWrapper').toggleClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.hamburgerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3462bc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b3c4e6;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
  /*padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;*/
  /*border: 5px solid yellow;*/
}
.hamburgerWrapper.active {
  left: 60%;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.hamburger {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.hamburger li a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 24px 16px 12px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-bottom: 5px transparent;*/
}
#toggle-nav:after {
  padding-left: 50px;
  content: 'Menu';
}
#toggle-nav span,
#toggle-nav span:before,
#toggle-nav span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
#toggle-nav span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#toggle-nav span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#toggle-nav span,
#toggle-nav span:before,
#toggle-nav span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#toggle-nav.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle-nav.active span:before,
#toggle-nav.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#toggle-nav.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-nav.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburgerWrapper">
  <ul class="hamburger">
    <li><a id="toggle-nav" href="#"><span></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For <kbd>1</kbd>, you can use `vertical-align: middle;` in combination with `display: inline-block;` for the menu text and the hamburger icon. You are positioning the 2 additional bars of the hamburger menu with absolute positioned elements, so you need to position the hamburger icon either `absolute` or `relative`. If you are using the vertical-alignment, you need to use `position: relative`. However, you could also use `box-shadow` for creating a hamburger menu (see <kbd>2</kbd>)

```css
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
```

Here it is applied onto your example:

```css
.hamburgerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3462bc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b3c4e6;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
  /*padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;*/
  /*border: 5px solid yellow;*/
}
.hamburgerWrapper.active {
  left: 60%;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.hamburger {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.hamburger li a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 24px 16px 12px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-bottom: 5px transparent;*/
}
#toggle-nav:after {
  padding-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: 'Menu';
}
#toggle-nav span,
#toggle-nav span:before,
#toggle-nav span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#toggle-nav span:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
}
#toggle-nav span:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
}
#toggle-nav span,
#toggle-nav span:before,
#toggle-nav span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#toggle-nav.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle-nav.active span:before,
#toggle-nav.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#toggle-nav.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-nav.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburgerWrapper">
  <ul class="hamburger">
    <li><a id="toggle-nav" href="#"><span></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

For <kbd>2</kbd>, you could just wrap the icon in a parent element with padding. Make sure, to include the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` (necessary, because your icon has an actual size which is smaller than it appears)

I used here `box-shadow` instead of `:before` and `:after`:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 8px 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.element {
  background: black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 black, 0 5px 0 0 black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

---

For <kbd>3</kbd>, you're better off using JavaScript, because you obviously want to do more than just coloring the elements (i.e. you need some logic which shows a menu, etc.).

However, it's easy to create a hover effect with CSS. If you want to have a click effect, you need to either use `:focus`, which only works, when the element is focused, or you use `:target`, like it is descriped in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17257848/3233827).

Here you can see the hover effect:

```css
.wrapper {
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}
.wrapper:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.wrapper:hover .hamburger-wrapper {
  border-color: red;
}
.wrapper:hover .hamburger {
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 green, 0 5px 0 0 green;
}
.wrapper:hover .menu {
  background: yellow;
  color: orange;
}
.menu {
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hamburger-wrapper {
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
  padding: 8px 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hamburger {
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
  background: black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 black, 0 5px 0 0 black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hamburger-wrapper">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">Menu</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much ssc-hrep3 but I'm having a little difficulty incorporating 1 into my code and getting it to work. I actually had 1 working but I think you changed the answer and I cant get the new answer to work (and cant remember the old one). I'm struggling with the element and menu divs and where they should go (or what they should replace). I know that is my lack of knowledge. For 2 yes got that working in the Fiddle and its exactly what I was looking for. For 3 I do indeed have JavaScript, ,which I have added to the above Fiddle, which currently opens my Hamburger menu.

Comment: I have added it again (I first applied it to your answer, but made it generic afterwards). For **3**, just add styles to the element `.hamburgerWrapper.active`.

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic ssc-hrep3, thank you so much. For some reason you can change the background easy enough with say (    background-color:blue; transition-property: background-color all;) but not the font and hamburger. Anyway that is something I can experiment with. Thanks again for all your help!!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure what you mean by "not the font and hamburger", if you want to change the font-family, then it is correct, this attribute is not animatable. The font color (`color`) or the font size (`font-size`) however is animatable (usable for transition). [Here is a list of animatable attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp). Try using `transition: 0.5s ease all;`

Comment: Sorry, I am still learning web design (day job c# developer but working hard on web design in my own time for about 4 months) so my terminology may not always be correct. By the Hamburger I meant basically the 3 lines and by the font I should have probably said text (i.e the Menu text)

Comment: @Damo Okay, nice :) But I'm still wondering, why you couldn't change the font or the hamburger. I've adapted example **3**, so maybe it helps you.