# Set CSS visibility to visible on button click - Reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to set a certain div to make visible on a button click event using `reactjs.` Is there a CSS only solution for this or do i have to handle it using `reactjs`. If so what's the approach I should take?

This is the div my buttons are placed

```
<div className="post_publish">
     <button className="preview_btn" href="#postpreview" onClick={this.preview}>Preview</button>
     <button className="post_btn">Post</button>
     <button className="cancel_btn" onClick={this.props.hideOverlay}>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I want to make the following div visible when I click the preview button

```
<div className="post_preview" id="postpreview">

</div>
```

`CSS` used in post_preview div

```
.post_preview {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This'll probably help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use javascript/react. One way is to do it like this:

Change the div to this:

```
<div className="post_preview" id="postpreview" style={{visibility: this.state.visibility }}>

</div>
```

For the functions

```
function preview()
{
    this.setState({visibility: 'visible'})
}

function hide_preview()
{
    this.setState({visibility: 'hidden'})
}
```

You will need to use state in this (I'm assuming you know how this works). The functions `preview` and `hide_preview` will be attached to the buttons that you want to preview and hide .

Comment: How is this changing the css of my post_preview div? My buttons are in a seperate div.

Comment: inline styles have priority over css. Your buttons being inside a separate div shouldn't matter as long as the whole thing is inside the same component, it shouldn't matter

Comment: @CraZyDroiD well at least you know how to use `bind` and `state` :)