# How to create button scaling effect in CSS?

Tags: css

I need a button whose after selector expands and gets disappeared when clicked. I need this effect via CSS.
[image]

When i click this button it's after selector expands.
Like

```
#button::after{
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

But this is not happening for me. Please help me. When clicked the after selector button should expand then should disappear. In a nutshell, i need button scaling effect.

Comment: Are you sure you want :after not active?? `#button:active{
  transform: scale(2);
}`

Comment: I mean i dont want to scale the button itself but want to scale ::after and ya via active.

Comment: The button disappears after clicking?

Comment: The ::after gets disappeared after clicking. Like i click a button it's ::after expands immediately and faster and gets disappeared. Please help

Comment: And ::after should have be same like actual button and should have `content=''`

Comment: you should post the rest of the css and html for the button.

Comment: As Dejan.S said: You should post the whole css and html for the button. Provide details and share your research please.

Comment: @jmag Please see the edited question

Comment: @Dejan.S Please see the edited question

Comment: @benedikt Please see the edited question

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

As far as I know you can't get an onclick event with CSS only and without using JavaScript. You can use :active, but this will only apply the style when the mouse button is held down. See [Bojangles answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13630259/1473041) on "[Can I have an Onclick effect in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630229/1473041)".

```css
#button {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

#button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 4px solid red;
  color: black;
  font-size: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform .3s ease, opacity .5s ease;
}
#button:active:after {
  transform: scale(5);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Ya after should disappear but there's should be no content and ::after border should expand.

Comment: Is that the effect you mean? Otherwise we need some more information about your current html/css code...

Comment: Sir, it's cool but when clicked immediately the full animation should run. In your script i just have to hold for some seconds then only ::after gets disappeared and i dont want to disapppear actual button border on click.

Comment: I woul'd like to have comments with downvotes, so i can improve my answer. As Dejan S. said - Bill should post the rest of the css and html for the button.

Comment: Can i put a animation so you guys can understand it? @benedikt

Answer (score 0):

**The code snippet is built upon on benedikt's answer.

`#button:after`'s border color is set to transparent, adds border-color during the animation. this creates the illusion that it disappears. I hope this helps.

```css
#button {
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid red;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

#button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  top:0;
  left:0;    
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  color: black;
  font-size: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.5s ease, border-color 0.1s ease;
}
#button:active:after {
  transform: scale(2);
  border-color:red;
  opacity: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<button id="button">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Why i have to hold it for long time? And why does blue outline appears after animation?

Comment: That is because it waits for the transition to finish. You can remove the transition but the effects will be sudden.

Comment: In this case, the transform will not be visible since the border is transparent. It will jump from `opacity:1;` with transparent to `opacity:0` with red. both are not visible. The effects that are visible takes place during transition time.