# Poor performance in Angular 4 when rendering a lot of elements with event handlers

Tags: html, css, angular, events, angular-material

I have a component which is basically a list of items, where each item contains a name and a row of boxes. 
Something like this (but styled): John Doe [1][2][3][4][5]
Each box represents a task, each task is either "approved" or "not approved". If it's approved it's green, if not then grey.
The data for each item is passed through from a Element object which also has an array of Task objects as one of its values and each box is attached to a (click) listener which toggles the value of task.approved and the color of the box, accordingly.

The problem arises when there are a lot of items in the list. I tested it with 90 items and each time I click on a box it takes up to 300ms to change its color.

**I tried a lot of different ways of rectifying this, here is the first iteration of the HTML:**

```html
<md-list>
      <md-list-item *ngFor="let item of testData" class="flex-container">
          <div style="margin-left:10px;"> {{item.firstName + " " + item.lastName}}</div>
          
          <div class="boxes">
              <div *ngFor="let task of item.tasks;"  style="cursor: pointer;" >
                  <div *NgIf="task.approved" class="flex-item box" style="background-color: green;" (click)="task.approved = !task.approved">{{task.taskNumber}}</div>
                  <div *NgIf="!task.approved" class="flex-item box" style="background-color: lightgrey;" (click)="task.approved = !task.approved">{{task.taskNumber}}</div>
              </div>
          </div>            
      </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

**TS:**

```js
export class App {
  testData: Element[];
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testData = [];
    for(var i=0; i<90; i++) {
      this.testData.push({
        id: i,
        firstName: "John" + (i + 1),
        lastName: "Doe",
        tasks: Task[],
      });
      for(var t=0; t<10; t++) {
        this.testData[i].tasks.push(
          {
            taskNumber: t+1,
            approved: (t%2 == 0) ? true: false //for variation sake
          }
        );
      }
      
    }
  }
}

export interface Element {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  tasks: Task[];
}

export interface Task {
  taskNumber: number;
  approved: boolean;
}
```

After this I tried:

- changing the Detection Strategy to onPush.
- adding a button which adds the listeners to the according row after you click it
- having only one listener and using the information from $event.target
- using pure CSS for handling click events and changing the color with this hack: [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

None of these made a noticeable improvement on the performance. I could also restrict the number of list items, but surely there is a different way of doing this.

Comment: try trackBy on both ngFor

Comment: I already have. Not entirely sure what it does, but I didn't notice a difference in performance.

Comment: I pasted your code into the default Material 2 plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/vQT0RcnztDK8yiortvf9?p=preview and the toggling (dont mind the layout) works instantly
Btw typo in  tasks: Task[], -> tasks: []

Comment: Have you tried modifying CSS instead of re-rendering the element? [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass); [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Comment: @Alexander hmm would the lack of CSS affect things? I also have a sidenav in my program and a few other elements

Comment: Depends on what is in that CSS/other components. I suggest you disable those components and then enable one by one.

Comment: @Alexander I ran your code on my machine and it's still slow. Plunker's servers are probably a lot more powerful than what I'm running on.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? @aframestor

Comment: @Garuuk I ended up having a separate pop up for approving tasks, and generating the html for the boxes in the component instead of dynamically in the template.