# CSS selector for Angular components with event binding

Tags: css, angular

Which CSS selector to use when applying a style to any component having an event binding?

```
<button (click)="doSomthing()">click me</button>
```

Something like this is not working.

```
[(click)]{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: So, If I understand properly, you would like define css style on click event. I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css) should answer your question.

Comment: No, for any event binding. event custom component with user defined events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rendered HTML, there is no attribute that corresponds to the Angular `(click)` event on the button. You can see that by inspecting the markup with the F12 tool in your browser. Therefore, you cannot use that event binding as a CSS selector. You would have to use another selector to identify the button (id, class, another attribute, etc.).

Comment: Yes, that is right. That is why I asked this here. I wanted to have one generic rule instead of adding a label (class, directive) to use it as a selector.