# Use CSS transition only for increasing value

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

In my code, I want to use the transition only when the width turns wider.
When the width decrease I don't want any animation.
can I do with CSS only? Add/remove classes is not an option for me.

```js
function changeCss() {
  document.getElementById('squareId').style.width = "300px";
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById('squareId').style.width = "100px";
}
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="squareId" class="square"></div>

<button onclick="changeCss()">increase</button>
<button onclick="reset()">decrease</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hd1u5y09/12/)

Comment: css action you can use `id:checked` select method follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css

Answer (score 6):

Adjust the transition at the same time in the JS code:

```js
window.changeCss = function() {
  document.getElementById('squareId').style.transition = "width 1s linear";
  document.getElementById('squareId').style.width = "300px";
}
window.reset = function() {
  document.getElementById('squareId').style.transition = "none";
  document.getElementById('squareId').style.width = "100px";
}
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="squareId" class="square">

</div>
<button onclick="changeCss()">increase</button>
<button onclick="reset()">decrease</button>
```