# Mimic click and unclick with CSS

Tags: css, onclick, click

Is there a way to mimic an 'unclick' event with CSS only? I was able to mimic a 'click' via transition property with time delay value. The action stays put for a long time as if the button has been clicked. How do I make this element 'unclicked', or retract it back to its original state? For instance, is there a way to click elsewhere on the screen and have the .sidebar (see the included code) be 'unclicked'?

```css
.sidebar > p {
  background: blue;
  width: 15em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0s 1000s;
  transition: all 0s 1000s;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar:active > p {
  background: blue;
  transform: translate(60px, -40px);
  width: 40em;
  transition: all 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='sidebar'> Sidebar
      <p>This is paragraph 1 inside sidebar </p>
      <p>This is paragraph 2 inside sidebar </p>
    </div>
    <div class='other'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your input.

FYI

1. This is not a homework project.
2. I'm aware of JavaScript. This exercise is for learning CSS.
3. I'm aware of other possible ways to mimic a click, like described here
   [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)
   or better yet here https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/

Comment: `I'm aware of other possible ways to mimic a click` --> so what do you expect ? i guess all them are there, not sure you will find more

Comment: I was hoping that maybe there is a way to achieve this without adding more HTML.

Comment: Not sure why you have a transition duration of 1000 seconds. If you want the animation to stay when you click on an element, then try using `:focus` with an anchor tag instead of setting a high transition duration.

Comment: you can use focus without extra element, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want extra element you can use the `:focus` combined with `tabindex` attribute to have the behavior of input element. So when you click outside you lose the focus and it's like the "unclick" you want:

```css
.sidebar {
  outline:none;
}

.sidebar > p {
  background: blue;
  width: 15em;
  position: relative;
  transition:1s;
}
.sidebar:focus > p {
  background: blue;
  transform: translate(60px, -40px);
  width: 40em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='sidebar' tabindex="-1"> Sidebar
    <p>This is paragraph 1 inside sidebar </p>
    <p>This is paragraph 2 inside sidebar </p>
  </div>
  <div class='other'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solved:

Use the combination of `transition-property-delay-value`, `active-pseudo-classes`, and `descendant-selectors`. Must also include `transition-property:none;`

```css
.wrapper .sidebar > p {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0s 1000s;
}

/* Click */
.wrapper .sidebar:active > p {
  visibility: visible;
}

/* Unclick */ 
.wrapper:active .sidebar > p {
  transition-property: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='wrapper'> Wrapper - unclick here
    <div class='sidebar'> Sidebar - click here
      <p>This is paragraph 1 inside sidebar. </p>
      <p>This is paragraph 2 inside sidebar. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```