# How do you change Material Icon permanently using CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, icons, google-material-icons

I am trying to change the icon permanently from "add" to "done" after I click the icon. If I click the icon again, it should change from "done" to "add."
I am wondering if it is possible to do this with CSS without using Javascript.

```css
.material-icons::before {
  content: "add";
}

section:active .material-icons::before {
  /*background-color: red;*/
  content: "done";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <span id="btn1" class="material-icons"></span>
</section>
```

Comment: `after I click it` --> click == javascript

Comment: ooh so there's no possibility of using css to do it?

Comment: you may consider some hack/workaround .. but what you describe is a JS job

Comment: No way with pure css, you need to handle the `click` event.

Comment: ahh i see.. alright then thanks for your advice!

Comment: There is 1 way with pure css, using a checkbox, but that's a bit hacky. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32721572/9288348

Comment: @Jeremy there is more than one way with hacky CSS ;)

Comment: hmm.. worth for a shot, thanks! I will try using checkbox.

Comment: @marchelee Why not use javascript? you can find an easy demo at w3 schools, is cleaner and takes less time then that checkbox hack.

Comment: @Jeremy I am not really good at Javascruipt hehehe but I will check w3 school for the tutorial.. thanks for your advice!!

Comment: @marchelee This would probably help: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp and for example this is one of the demos that changes something onclick: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_addeventlistener

Comment: @Jeremy woaah thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest CSS checkbox hack solution, you can start from here:

```css
/* The hack */
input[type=checkbox] {
   display:none;
}
label {
  -webkit-appearance: push-button;
  -moz-appearance: button; 
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Default State */
input[type=checkbox] + section .material-icons::before {
   content:"add";
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + section .material-icons::before {
   content:"done";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Open+Sans"
  rel="stylesheet">

<label>Click Me
<input type="checkbox">
<section>
  <span id="btn1" class="material-icons"></span>
</section>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! @Balázs Varga

Comment: @JamesDouglas what? It'll change the icon, but also scroll to the top of the page (default `button` behaviour). Tested in latest Chrome, FF, and even in IE11 (which don't show the element as a button, but everything else is working).

Comment: `but also scroll to the top of the page (default button behaviour)` --> and you think this side effect has no importance ? for me it make the whole thing bad

Comment: @BalázsVarga The OP seems to be implying that the button should stay on `done` *permanantly* after it has been clicked once.

Comment: @BalázsVarga What you have currently works *exactly the same* as [what the OP has](https://jsfiddle.net/pqpd7ndL/).

Comment: @TemaniAfif I added a button element for semantic reasons but it works with any element, a div or span and this side effect will gone.

Comment: @JamesDouglas `I am trying to change the icon permanently from "add" to "done" after I click the icon. If I click the icon again, it should change from "done" to "add".` So what does it mean exactly?

Comment: For me using internet Chrome it works correctly (unless he means that it also should remain this way after refreshing the page).

Comment: If this is the case it's impossible with CSS only, so I think the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way this works, is there are two `<span>`'s, (one with the `add` and one with the `done` icon) and a checkbox all stacked on top of each other, an the `done` icon is hidden. The `add` icon is `pointer-events: none;`, and when you click on it the checkbox gets checked. Then the `add` icon gets hidden, and the `done` icon gets shown.

(Only works if you click directly on the text)

```css
.done,
.add, .done {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.done { display: none; }
.add { display: inline-block; pointer-events: none; }
label {
  
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
input[type=checkbox] { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
input[type=checkbox]:checked~.done { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="checkbox">
<div class="add">
  <span id="btn1" class="material-icons first">add</span>
</div>
<div class="done">
  <span id="btn1" class="material-icons">done</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have run your code but the result is still the same like mine.. Ah and yes, I am using chrome

Comment: @JamesDouglas This only changes when you have your mouse pressed, when you let go the click button it just changes back to the previous icon again for me (using chrome)

Comment: @marchelee Ok, I've fixed it. Enjoy!