# How to change CSS on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 4 cards which contain data. I want when first header text card is clicked, it expand upward, and info I displayed and when clicked the same card it hide the body but the rest card stays the same,

Here is visual of what I want.

[image]

> UPDATE

Here is JSFiddle with all four cards: http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/rzjxkv8e/2/
Here is HTML:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="data">

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
            card header
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="test-block" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
            card block
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
            card header
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="test-block" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
            card block
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
            card header
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="test-block" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
            card block
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
            card header
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="test-block" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
            card block
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is JavaScript

```
$('.card-header').click(function(){
    $('.card').toggleClass('.card-size')
})
```

Here is CSS

```
.data{
  display: flex;
}

.card-size{
  height: 224px;
}
```

Comment: What is not working with it? In your fiddle it expands when I click it, but the top of the box is already at the top, so It cannot expand up from what is in your fiddle.

Comment: First of all, your class to toggle has a point. It shouldn't: toggleClass('card-size'). The point is part of the selector, not of the class. And then, your selector inside the click function selects all .card elements, not those inside the card header selected.

Comment: try using `$(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('.card-size')`

Comment: Here is how you would do this in CSS, though it is considered a hack. If you can use JS then you should go that route, instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css

Comment: @Pete you solution expaands down not upward, and I will need to create a function for each card so that when I click one , the rest stays the same right now  you click one everything goes down, any idea? I want a user to be able to click any card and the card should expand upward

Comment: @TylerH thanks but I prefer jquery or pure javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9musLxy4/98/

Comment: @MichaelCurry Thanks for your help but your method is not working as I want, when u click the header title it slide down the title and slide up the body that is wrong when u click the header title it should slide up  as image show, u can see urself that ur result does not resembles to what I want, but thank you alot for your effort

Comment: Using collapse or jQuery slideUp/slideDown obviously don't work, you'll need to write your own CSS animation to make that happen but I've already spent 2+ hours looking at this for you so you'll have to figure that bit out yourself, do a Google search for CSS animations.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a JSFiddle with a working solution.

I've stripped out the collapse attributes and pulled it down to barebones.

http://jsfiddle.net/9musLxy4/88/

HTML:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="data">

<div class='card-container' data-card-id='1'>
  <div class='card-header' data-card-id='1'>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class='card-body collapse' data-card-id='1'>
    <div class='data'>
      Body 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='card-container' data-card-id='2'>
  <div class='card-header' data-card-id='2'>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class='card-body collapse' data-card-id='2'>
    <div class='data'>
      Body 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='card-container' data-card-id='3'>
  <div class='card-header' data-card-id='3'>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class='card-body collapse' data-card-id='3'>
    <div class='data'>
      Body 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='card-container' data-card-id='4'>
  <div class='card-header' data-card-id='4'>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class='card-body collapse' data-card-id='4'>
    <div class='data'>
      Body 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.data{
  display: flex;
}

.card-body {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.card-container').on('click', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).data('card-id')
    $('.card-body[data-card-id="' + id + '"]').toggle()
})
```

Comment: ouch, this would mean you would have to program a click event for each card you create - not very scalable

Comment: True, my jquery is so rusty I couldnt - with certainty - suggest how to dynamically add the toggled class on the parent and be confident it is correct. Feel free to expand on the answer.

Comment: Thanks to Michael Curry for improving on my answer with the addition of a wildcard selector.

Comment: unfortunately now your answer makes no sense as there is no card header with an id - there's a card with an id, or an inner element with a class of card header, but not one with both

Comment: Yeah, I've realised that my changes actually just break your stuff. Let me have another crack at it real quick!

Comment: heheh, sorry, I should have checked the changes. I really shouldnt stack overflow when working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.card-header').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('.card-size');
    $(this).parent().find('#test-block').toggleClass('show')
})
```

Use this

Comment: Hi siya, this is not  what I want,  I have four cards, each card contain data, I want when user click one of the card it should expand upward and display the data, the rest of the card should be the same, a user can click any card,  check the visual image for what I want, Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to change the size of the card in general when it is expanded? If so, lose the JQuery, you just need a CSS style:

```
#test-block .card-body {
  height: 224px;
}
```

If you want to the card size to remain the same after you open it, then you would not want to toggle the size class, but simply add it.

```
$('.card-header').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.card').addClass('card-size');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9musLxy4/74/

Comment: Hii Esten this is not what I want , here isw clear image of what I need https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkHlz.png , jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/rzjxkv8e/6/  when a user click one of the card it should exapnd upward