# How can i remove splash screen on logout?

Tags: html, jquery, css, splash-screen

I am making login and logout page with splash screen but splash screen is working fine on load page I didn't use jquery/javascript.I created with splash screen in css3 animation when i clicked logout button it same thing repeated again splash screen on logout clicked.I don't want splash screen on click logout button i want to only onload page starting page after that i want to remove splash screen on click logout.but it's repeating same animation on logout.how can i do remove on logout click? i tried .hide(),.remove() but it's not working please help me.. how can i make code on load and logout?

Css3 animation

```
/* SPLASH SCREEN * -------------------------- */

#splash {
    background-color: #fc9204 !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 10;
    transition-property: top;
    -webkit-animation: slide-out-fwd-center  7.45s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
animation: slide-out-fwd-center  7.45s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  }

 @-webkit-keyframes slide-out-fwd-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(1);
            transform: translateZ(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(600px);
            transform: translateZ(600px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-out-fwd-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(1);
            transform: translateZ(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(600px);
            transform: translateZ(600px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

 #splash img {
  display: block;
  margin: 200px auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-animation: slide-fwd-center 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
animation: slide-fwd-center 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;

}


@-webkit-keyframes slide-fwd-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(160px);
            transform: translateZ(160px);
  }
}
@keyframes slide-fwd-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(160px);
            transform: translateZ(160px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply! but i am looking in jquery it's not working css3 properly. i mentioned here my code how can i stop splash screen on logout click.i have no idea. I am looking on click button  after remove all css id and show login page without splash screen on jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link to a previous SO question already asked.

[Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

It shows you how to check for a click in CSS but I would recommend using JavaScript to check for a click. It is versatile and capable of doing so much more. It’s worth understanding the basics at least to create some great webpages.