# There is a hover CSS state is it possible to also add a CSS click state?

Tags: html, css

There is a hover CSS state is it possible to also add a CSS click state?

In the example the browser responds to a mouse hover event and apply specific styles then. Can you do the same on click event?

Supported:

```
#menu:hover
```

No response:

```
#menu:click
```

```css
.menu {
   display: none;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

button {
  padding: 12px;
}

#hoverMenu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#hoverMenu:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}


#clickMenu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#clickMenu:click .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hoverMenu">
   <button>Menu on hover</button>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="clickMenu">
   <button>Menu on click</button>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Use cases:

- when you want menus to show on click rather than on hover
- when you want to show pop overs that are appropriate to show on click rather than show on hover.
- when you are not able to use JavaScript or when it would be unnecessary

Does anyone else want to see this in the CSS spec?

Comment: No, there isn't anything like this. You need Javascript for that.

Answer (score 1):

there is no css for that you need js for doing click event.the close match is :active or :target
but there is a trick or hack in order to do that. and your question already answered here:
[Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

hope this help you.