# How to change background color of iconbutton when onclick in material ui

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui

[image: Background image when onClick]

When I clicked `IconButton` the background color changed to an oval shape. I need to change the background color after `onclick`

### CSS

CSS for `IconButton`. Changed the background color when hover. I need the same for `onClick`

```js
const positionStyle = makeStyles(theme => ({
    paper: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.accent[100],
      },
      iconButton: {
        padding: "10px",
        margin: "0 5px 1px 0",
        "&:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible, &:active": {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.accent[100],
        },
        "&$buttonDisabled": {
          color: theme.palette.accent[100],
        },
      },
    })
```

### Material UI

```
<Paper className={classes.paper}>
    <Box display={"flex"} height={theme.spacing(2.3)}>
        <IconButton
         color={"inherit"}
         size={"small"}
         className={classes.iconButton}
         onClick={() => {
             history.push("/a")
         }}>
            <img src={"/static/images//a.svg"} />
            <Box pl={1} mt={"-4px"} maxWidth={theme.spacing(10)}>
                <Typography variant={"subtitle1"} component="p">
                    {" Hello"}
                </Typography>
            </Box>
        </IconButton>
    </Box>
</Paper>
```

Comment: Please upload your `code`

Comment: Please find the attached image and code. I need to change the background color either teal or full grey. not in oval shape.

Answer (score 0):

as i read here
[Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)
the best way to do this is a checkbox trick,
other solutions are also on the page i linked

either if you have more liberty you can use JS

Have a good day