# Carousel slider with indicator navigation - is a "CSS-only" design possible?

Tags: html, css

Right now, the navigations/anchors are numerical numbers, but I want a design that is sorta "indicator", meaning instead of clicking the numbers to navigate, the user can click on round circles(with no numbers) to jump to different slides, and the ***corresponding circles turned dark*** when the slides are selected.

So....Is it possible by using ONLY CSS?

```css
  html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f2f3f7;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

.slider {
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #f2f3f7;
}

.slider>a {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 26px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3);
  color: rgba(108, 18, 144, 0.8);
}

.slider>a:active {
  background: black;
}

.slidescontainer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  background: #f2f3f7;
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.slidescontainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1rem;
}

.slidescontainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.slidescontainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: black;
}

.slidescontainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
  .slidescontainer>div {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    border-radius: 3rem;
    background: #f2f3f7;
    box-shadow: 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .slidescontainer #slide-1,
  #slide-2,
  #slide-3,
  #slide-4 {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .slide-title {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
  <a href="#slide-2">2</a>
  <a href="#slide-3">3</a>
  <a href="#slide-4">4</a>

  <div class="slidescontainer">
    <div id="slide-1">
      <div class="slide-title">1st slide, text-align: justify</div>
      <div style="font-size: 12px; text-align: justify; padding-left: 30px; padding-right:30px;">Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin</div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2">
      <div class="slide-title">2nd slide, text-align: left</div>
      <div style="font-size: 12px; text-align: left; padding-left: 30px;">Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin</div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3">
      <div class="slide-title">3rd slide, text-align: end</div>
      <div style="font-size: 12px; text-align: end; padding-right: 30px;">Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin</div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4">
      <div class="slide-title">4th slide, text-align: right</div>
      <div style="font-size: 12px; text-align: right; padding-right: 30px;">Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: while this **could**  be possible using [the checkbox hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32721572/14776809) to simulate an on-click event in CSS, it would be an extremely messy and awkward solution. i highly suggest looking into doing this in javascript

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/can-get-pretty-far-making-slider-just-html-css/ and https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/create-a-slider-with-pure-CSS/ They're both good CSS only solutions but they have limitations that JS would be required in order to appropriately address