# Is it possible to both hide and show different div/elements using :target

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a url where I used target, example: [www.hello.com/#targeturl](http://www.hello.com/#targeturl)

I want to use that to hide an element, and also show a different element that's hidden. Is there a way to go about doing this?

The way I tried doing it was by using the below to show two "display: none" elements

```html
<div id="targeturl" class="classy">
<div id="targeturl" class="classier">
```

and then used the CSS:

```css
#targeturl.classy:target {
    display: block!important;
}

#targeturl.classier:target {
    display: block!important;
}
```

But of course this doesn't work, is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: You have assigned the same ID value to two different elements, which is not valid HTML. IDs must be unique within the document.

Comment: So does this make this essentially impossible then? In terms of using www.hello.com/#targeturl to both hide and show (when someone visits that specific url), since there's no way to add to different divs to a url like www.hello.com/#targeturl#targeturl2

Comment: I don’t think it is possible, why don’t you use javascript to do the hide-show effect?

Comment: To achieve what I explained, are you able to tell me how to do that please?

Comment: I figured it out with Javascript as you said, no need to explain how to do it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without JS using [the `<label>` – `<input type="checkbox">` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32721572):

```css
.classy, .classier {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

input:checked ~ .classy,
input:not(:checked) ~ .classier {
  display: block;
}

.classy {
  background: #eee8aa;
}

.classier {
  background: #96e3ce;
}
```

```html
<a href="#targeturl">
  <label for="targeturl">Click me!</label>
</a>

<!-- This is meant to be hidden -->
<input type="checkbox" id="targeturl">

<div class="classy">.classy</div>
<div class="classier">.classier</div>
```

Note that this will scroll to the checkbox instead of the two `<div>`s. Setting a different `id` for it (or hide it using `display: none`/`visibility: hidden`) will effectively remove this behaviour altogether.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution using `:target`

As said in the comments, ID should be unique, but we can still use unique ID to show/hide elements with CSS.

As long as the ID is attached in an element that is at least **the lowest common ancestor** and **the oldest** of the elements you want to hide (classy, classiest, classiest), we can use CSS sibling combinator (~) and do this:

```css
.classy,
.classier,
.classiest {
  display: none;
}

#targeturl:target.classy,
#targeturl:target~.classier,
#targeturl:target~* .classiest {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#targeturl">SHOW</a> | <a href="#">HIDE</a>

<div id="targeturl" class="classy">
  hidden classy
</div>
<div>
  something not hidden
</div>
<div class="classier">
  hidden classier
</div>
<div>
  yet again something not hidden
</div>
<div>
  another thing not hidden
  <div class="classiest">
    hidden classiest
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're fine with changing the HTML structure, it's also better to attach the ID to the parent of the elements you want to hide:

```css
.classy,
.classier,
.classiest {
  display: none;
}

#targeturl:target .classy,
#targeturl:target .classier,
#targeturl:target .classiest {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#targeturl">SHOW</a> | <a href="#">HIDE</a>

<div id="targeturl">
  <div class="classy">
    hidden classy
  </div>
  <div>
    something not hidden
  </div>
  <div class="classier">
    hidden classier
  </div>
  <div>
    yet again something not hidden
  </div>
  <div>
    another thing not hidden
    <div class="classiest">
      hidden classiest
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```