# Colour Swatches border on hover/selected variants

Tags: css

I am trying to create an effect on my colour swatches where if you hover over a swatch or select a swatch a black solid border appears around the swatch with a small gap of white space between the swatch and new border.

image:

[image: see image].

I tried scaling up the size of the swatch & then adding a black border surrounding a white border, and inseting the original swatch to create the illusion of a gap, however I did not implement this correctly (see following code), as all that occurs on selected variants is a quick transition followed by no border.

image where pink is selected:

[image: see image where pink is selected].

```
.color-swatches {
  display: flex;
}

.color-swatch {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px; /* Adjust the width of each color swatch */
  height: 30px; /* Adjust the height of each color swatch */
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.color-swatch::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}

.color-swatch:hover::before,
.color-swatch input[type="radio"]:checked + span::before {
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}

.color-swatch input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.color-swatch span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #4b4b4b;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.color-swatch input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  border-color: #000;
  transform: scale(1.2); /* Scale up the swatch when selected */
}

.color-swatch input[type="radio"]:checked + span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -2px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transform: scale(1.2); /* Scale up the gap illusion border when selected */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.color-swatch input[type="radio"]:checked + span:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1.3); /* Further scale up the gap illusion border on hover when selected */
}
```

Following is the Liquid/HTML code I use for the variant swatches:

```
    <legend class="form__label" id="option-{{ option.name | handle }}">{{ option.name }}: <span id="selected-{{ option.name | handle }}">{{ option.selected_value }}</span></legend>
     <div class="color-swatches">
           {%- for value in option.values -%}
               {%- assign variant = product.variants | where: option.name, value | first -%}
               {%- assign swatchColor = '' -%}
               {%- case value -%}
                   {%- when 'Pink' -%}
                       {%- assign swatchColor = '#E3BAB3' -%}
                   {%- when 'Lilac' -%}
                       {%- assign swatchColor = '#CBB9E0' -%}
                   {%- when 'Navy' -%}
                       {%- assign swatchColor = '#415873' -%}
                   {%- when 'Red' -%}
                       {%- assign swatchColor = '#D63238' -%}
                   {%- when 'Tan' -%}
                       {%- assign swatchColor = '#E1BC9F' -%}
                   {%- else -%}
                       {%- assign swatchColor = '' -%}
               {%- endcase -%}
               <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="color-swatch" style="background-color: {{ swatchColor }};">
                   <input type="radio" id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                       name="{{ option.name }}"
                       value="{{ value | escape }}"
                       form="{{ product_form_id }}"
                       {% if option.selected_value == value %}checked{% endif %}
                       onchange="updateSelectedValue('{{ option.name | handle }}', '{{ value | escape }}')"
                   >
                   <span></span>
               </label>
           {%- endfor -%}
       </div>
```

Comment: I recommend posting a couple of the swatches' HTML elements. That will make it easier for users to test it out and provide the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question doesn't include a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So I'm only going to touch on the `border` thing, because I think that's your main focus, and I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to say about the `transition` effect. If I understand you correctly, you want it to appear as if there is a transparent gap between color swatch and border.

**UPDATE:** I have now also implemented a `select`/`unselect` function (see the two snippets at the end of the answer). However, this was implemented using `JavaScript`. It is only a few lines. There is also a CSS based solution, rather it's a CSS hack. More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32721572/20896315) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

I'm going to **show you three ways**, but only one of them creates a real gap and the other two fake it. This fact is especially important if you are using an image, pattern or gradient as a background.

### Use the `outline` property

This is probably the fastest and easiest way. Simply assign `element:hover` a regular `border` in combination with an `outline` border, where the regular border has to be the color of the background. So **this method is fake** and a background other than a single color is suboptimal. Another thing that needs to be mentioned. The element in the normal state (no hover) needs a transparent border that has exactly the same width as in the hover state. Otherwise there would be a change in size, which looks ugly.

```
element {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

element:hover {
    border:  3px solid white;  /* matches background color */
    outline: 4px solid black;  /* any color */
}
```

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/outline

### Use the `::after` pseudo element

One thing right away, **this method also only fakes** everything. So how is it done? First the actual element must be positioned `relative`, since the `::after` pseudo element will be set to `absolute`. A transparent border is also required here for the same reason as in the previous example. Next, like before, assign `element:hover` a regular `border`, where the regular border has to be the color of the background. Finally, the `::after` pseudo-element for the `:hover` state. As already mentioned, this must be set to `position:absolute`. The `background-color` serves as the `border-color` and we get the desired `border-width` by using `top`, `right`, `bottom`and `left` property with a negative value. Again, it should be said here, anything other than a single color as the background color would be suboptimal.

```
element {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

element:hover {
    border: 3px solid white;  /* matches background color */
}

element:hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    right: -7px;
    bottom: -7px;
    background: black;  /* any color */
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org//docs/Web/CSS/::after

### Use the `background-clip` property

The best always comes last, and that's probably what you'll need, **nothing faked, but a real gap created**. As the title suggests, this method uses the `background-clip` property set to `content-box`. Probably the biggest advantage here is that the background can be designed as you wish. Color gradient, patterns or images, everything is possible. Everything else here is actually self-explanatory, since everything has already been described in the two previous methods.

```
element {
    width: 66px;
    height: 66px;
}

element:hover {
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: -3px;
    border: 4px solid black;  /* any color */
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

### A working example

I have created two snippets to show in a working example what I have just discussed. In the first one a solid color background is used. Here all methods work perfectly, whereas in the second snippet a background pattern is in use. The difference is now clearly visible.

**Snippet 1 - solid background color:**

```js
let swatches = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');

let selected = (e) => {
   let swatch = e.target;
   swatch.classList.toggle('selected');
}

swatches.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', selected);
});
```

```css
/* General Styling */

.color-1 { background: pink; }
.color-2 { background: thistle; }
.color-3 { background: steelblue; }
.color-4 { background: crimson; }
.color-5 { background: burlywood; }

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    column-gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container h2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
}

.container .swatch {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Swatch Styling */

/* using outline property */

#outline .swatch {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

#outline .swatch:hover {
    border: 3px solid white; 
    outline: 4px solid black;
}

#outline .swatch.selected {
    border: 3px solid white;
    outline: 4px solid orange;
}

/* using ::after pseudo element */

#pseudo .swatch {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

#pseudo .swatch:hover {
    border: 3px solid white;
}

#pseudo .swatch:hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    right: -7px;
    bottom: -7px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#pseudo .swatch.selected {
    border: 3px solid white;
}

#pseudo .swatch.selected::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    right: -7px;
    bottom: -7px;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* using background-clip property */

#clip .swatch {
    width: 66px;
    height: 66px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#clip .swatch:hover {
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: -3px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

#clip .swatch.selected {
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: -3px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 4px solid orange;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="outline" class="container">
    <h2>Outline Method</h2>
    <div class="swatch color-1"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-2"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-3"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-4"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-5"></div>
</div>

<div id="pseudo" class="container">
    <h2>Pseudo Element</h2>
    <div class="swatch color-1"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-2"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-3"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-4"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-5"></div>
</div>

<div id="clip" class="container">
    <h2>Background Clip</h2>
    <div class="swatch color-1"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-2"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-3"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-4"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-5"></div>
</div>
```

**Snippet 2 - background pattern:**

```js
let swatches = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');

let selected = (e) => {
   let swatch = e.target;
   swatch.classList.toggle('selected');
}

swatches.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', selected);
});
```

```css
/* General Styling */

body {
   background: url('https://i.imgur.com/8uEAmBx.jpg') repeat;
}

.color-1 { background: pink; }
.color-2 { background: thistle; }
.color-3 { background: steelblue; }
.color-4 { background: crimson; }
.color-5 { background: burlywood; }

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    column-gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container h2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
}

.container .swatch {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Swatch Styling */

/* using outline property */

#outline .swatch {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

#outline .swatch:hover {
    border: 3px solid white; 
    outline: 4px solid black;
}

#outline .swatch.selected {
    border: 3px solid white;
    outline: 4px solid orange;
}

/* using ::after pseudo element */

#pseudo .swatch {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

#pseudo .swatch:hover {
    border: 3px solid white;
}

#pseudo .swatch:hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    right: -7px;
    bottom: -7px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#pseudo .swatch.selected {
    border: 3px solid white;
}

#pseudo .swatch.selected::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    right: -7px;
    bottom: -7px;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* using background-clip property */

#clip .swatch {
    width: 66px;
    height: 66px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#clip .swatch:hover {
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: -3px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

#clip .swatch.selected {
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: -3px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 4px solid orange;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="outline" class="container">
    <h2>Outline Method</h2>
    <div class="swatch color-1"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-2"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-3"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-4"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-5"></div>
</div>

<div id="pseudo" class="container">
    <h2>Pseudo Element</h2>
    <div class="swatch color-1"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-2"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-3"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-4"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-5"></div>
</div>

<div id="clip" class="container">
    <h2>Background Clip</h2>
    <div class="swatch color-1"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-2"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-3"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-4"></div>
    <div class="swatch color-5"></div>
</div>
```