# Clicking on an element changes the classNames of all the items inside the map

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to get a press animation on the card once I click the button. I am doing that by changing the *className* back and forth every time the button is clicked. But the issue is that clicking the button changes the className of all the elements inside the map. Does anyone has any idea where I am messing up?

If you hover over the *shoulders* card:
[image]

If you click on it, ideally only one card should show pressing animation, but here all cards are showing the animation.

[image]

[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
const [chosenRoutine, setChosenRoutine] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
    setChosenRoutine("");
}, []);

<Stack
    direction="row"
    sx={{
        justifyContent: "center",
        gap: "80px",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
    }}>
    {chosenRegimeData.routine.map((routine, index) => (
        <Box
            key={index}
            sx={{
                borderRadius: "30px",
            }}>
            <Box
                className={classNames}
                sx={{
                    display: "grid",
                    width: "400px",
                    height: "370px",
                    borderRadius: "30px",
                    p: "10px",
                    background: "rgba(10, 18, 38, 1)",
                    position: "relative",
                }}>
                <img
                    src={routine.image}
                    alt="image"
                    style={{
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "70%",
                        borderRadius: "30px",
                    }}
                />
                <Stack
                    alignItems="center"
                    spacing={1}
                    sx={{
                        width: "100%",
                        background: "rgba(10, 18, 38, 1)",
                        position: "absolute",
                        bottom: "20px",
                        pt: "2px",
                        borderRadius: "30px",
                    }}>
                    <Typography
                        className="gradient-text-2"
                        sx={{
                            width: "100%",
                            color: "#fff",
                            textTransform: "capitalize",
                            textAlign: "center",
                            fontSize: "24px",
                        }}>
                        {routine.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                        <Button
                            size="large"
                            variant="outlined"
                            className="gradient-text-5"
                            onClick={() => {
                                setClassNames("pressed-2");
                                console.log("pressed", index);
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    setClassNames("increase-shadow-on-hover");
                                    // showRoutineExercises(routine);
                                }, 300);
                            }}>
                            See Exercises in this Routine
                        </Button>
                    </Stack>
                </Stack>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    ))}
</Stack>
```

**Formate of *chosenRegimeData***

```
{
        name: "calisthenics",
        warmup: [
            {
                name: "neck rotations",
                time: "20 seconds",
                image: neckRotation,
            },
            {
                name: "arm rotations",
                time: "10 seconds",
                image: armRotation,
            },
            {
                name: "arm side swings",
                time: "10 seconds",
                image: armSideSwings,
            },
            {
                name: "jumping jacks",
                time: "10 seconds",
                image: jumpingJacks,
            },
            {
                name: "heel flicks",
                time: "10 seconds",
                image: heelFlicks,
            },
            {
                name: "high knees",
                time: "10 seconds",
                image: highKnees,
            },
            {
                name: "dynamic quad pull",
                reps: "5 each side",
                image: quadPull,
            },
            {
                name: "toe hand touch",
                reps: "10 each side",
                image: toeHandTouch,
            },
            {
                name: "wide stance side to side",
                reps: "5 each side",
                image: wideStanceSideToSide,
            },
            {
                name: "wide stance forward bend",
                reps: "10 each side",
                image: wideStanceForwardBend,
            },
        ],
        routine: [
            {
                name: "chest and triceps",
                image: chest,
                exercise: [
                    {
                        name: "pushups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: pushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "diamond pushups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: diamondPushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "wide pushups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: widePushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "tricep dips",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: tricepDips,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "tricep extensions",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: tricepExtensions,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "decline pushups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: declinePushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "incline pushups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: inclinePushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "explosive pushups",
                        sets: 2,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: explosivePushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "archer pushups",
                        sets: 2,
                        reps: 4,
                        image: archerPushups,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: "shoulders",
                image: shoulders,
                exercise: [
                    {
                        name: "pike pushups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: pikePushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "raised pike pushups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 8,
                        image: raisedPikePushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "wall walk",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: wallWalk,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "handstand against the wall",
                        sets: 3,
                        time: "20 seconds",
                        image: handstandAgainstWall,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "handstand pushups against wall",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 5,
                        image: handstand,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: "back and biceps",
                image: back,
                exercise: [
                    {
                        name: "pullups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 6,
                        image: pullups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "chinups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 6,
                        image: chinups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "wide pullups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 5,
                        image: widePullups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "close grip pullups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 5,
                        image: closeGripPullups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "assisted pullups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 7,
                        image: assistedPullups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "assisted chinups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 7,
                        image: assistedChinups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "scapula shrugs",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 10,
                        image: scapulaShrugs,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "australian pullups",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 25,
                        image: australianPullups,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: "legs",
                image: legs,
                exercise: [
                    {
                        name: "squats",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 50,
                        image: squats,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "lunges",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 50,
                        image: lunges,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "calf raises",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 50,
                        image: calfRaises,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "jump squats",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 20,
                        image: jumpSquats,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "jump lunges",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 20,
                        image: jumpLunges,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "pistol squats",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 5,
                        image: pistolSquats,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "single leg calf raises",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 20,
                        image: singleLegCalfRaises,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: "core",
                image: core,
                exercise: [
                    {
                        name: "plank",
                        sets: 3,
                        time: "90 seconds",
                        image: plank,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "side plank",
                        sets: 3,
                        time: "60 seconds",
                        image: sidePlank,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "reverse plank",
                        sets: 3,
                        time: "60 seconds",
                        image: reversePlank,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "russian twists",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 40,
                        image: russianTwists,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "leg raises",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 40,
                        image: legRaises,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "bicycle crunches",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 40,
                        image: bicycleCrunches,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "flutter kicks",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 40,
                        image: flutterKicks,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "chair situps",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 40,
                        image: chairSitups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "v situps",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 20,
                        image: vSitups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "crucifix",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 20,
                        image: crucifix,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "side plank up and down",
                        sets: 3,
                        reps: 15,
                        image: sidePlankUpAndDown,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: "cardio",
                image: cardio,
                exercise: [
                    {
                        name: "jumping jacks",
                        time: "45 seconds",
                        image: jumpingJacks,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "high knees",
                        time: "45 seconds",
                        image: highKnees,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "butt kicks",
                        time: "45 seconds",
                        image: heelFlicks,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "burpees",
                        reps: 10,
                        image: jumpingJacks,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "mountain climbers",
                        time: "45 seconds",
                        image: crossMountainClimbers,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "jump rope",
                        time: "45 seconds",
                        image: jumpRope,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "sprint",
                        time: "20 seconds",
                        image: running,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "explosive pushups",
                        time: "30 seconds",
                        image: explosivePushups,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "jump squats",
                        time: "30 seconds",
                        image: jumpSquats,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
        cooldown: [
            {
                name: "toe touch",
                time: "20 seconds",
                sets: 2,
                image: toeTouch,
            },
            {
                name: "toe touch with leg spread",
                time: "20 seconds",
                sets: 2,
                image: toeTouchWithLegSpread,
            },
            {
                name: "single leg hamstring stretch",
                time: "20 seconds",
                sets: 2,
                image: singleLegHamstringStretch,
            },
            {
                name: "butterfly stretch",
                time: "20 seconds",
                sets: 1,
                image: butterflyStretch,
            },
            {
                name: "knee to chest",
                time: "5 seconds",
                sets: 4,
                image: kneeToChest,
            },
            {
                name: "waist twist",
                time: "10 seconds",
                sets: 2,
                image: waistTwist,
            },
            {
                name: "cobra stretch",
                time: "20 seconds",
                sets: 1,
                image: cobraStretch,
            },
        ],
    },
```

**Here are the corresponding styles**

```
.pressed-2,
.pressed-2:hover {
    animation: press-2 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
}

@keyframes press-2 {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: 1px 10px 5px 1px #c471ed;
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(5px);
        box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px 1px #24fe41;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(0) translateY(0);
        box-shadow: 1px 10px 5px 1px #c471ed;
    }
}

.increase-shadow-on-hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px 1px #12c2e9 !important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease !important;
}

.increase-shadow-on-hover:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 10px 5px 1px #c471ed !important;
    transform: translateY(-5px) !important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease !important;
}
```

In the other places, the same thing is working properly. For eg:

```
const WorkoutCard = ({
    image,
    name,
    btnContent,
    btnAction,
    isDelete,
    deleteAction,
}) => {
    const [classNames, setClassNames] = useState("increase-shadow-on-hover");
    return (
        <Stack
            className={classNames}
            alignItems="center"
            sx={{
                width: "260px",
                height: "240px",
                borderRadius: "30px",
                p: "10px",
                background: "rgba(10, 18, 38, 1)",
                position: "relative",
            }}>
            <img
                src={image}
                alt="image"
                style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "70%",
                    borderRadius: "30px",
                }}
            />
            <Stack
                alignItems="center"
                spacing={1}
                sx={{
                    width: "100%",
                    background: "rgba(10, 18, 38, 1)",
                    position: "absolute",
                    bottom: "7px",
                    pt: "2px",
                    borderRadius: "30px",
                }}>
                <Typography
                    className="gradient-text-2"
                    sx={{
                        width: "100%",
                        color: "#fff",
                        textTransform: "capitalize",
                        textAlign: "center",
                        fontSize: "18px",
                    }}>
                    {name}
                </Typography>
                <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                    <Button
                        size="medium"
                        variant="outlined"
                        className="gradient-text-5"
                        onClick={() => {
                            setClassNames("pressed-2");
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                setClassNames("increase-shadow-on-hover");
                                btnAction();
                            }, 300);
                        }}>
                        {btnContent}
                    </Button>
                    {isDelete && (
                        <DeleteIcon
                            onClick={() => {
                                setClassNames("pressed-2");
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    setClassNames("increase-shadow-on-hover");
                                    deleteAction();
                                }, 300);
                            }}
                            sx={{
                                color: "#ff3232",
                                ml: "10px",
                                cursor: "pointer",
                            }}
                        />
                    )}
                </Stack>
            </Stack>
        </Stack>
    );
};
```

[image: Here it works]

Here is the full code of the component that isn't working properly, if you need:)

```
const RoutineSection = ({
    chosenRegimeData,
    addWorkout,
    removeWorkout,
    hide,
    setHide,
    rows,
    columns,
    handleCellEditStop,
}) => {
    const [chosenRoutine, setChosenRoutine] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
        setChosenRoutine("");
    }, []);

    const showRoutineExercises = (routine) => {
        setChosenRoutine(routine);
    };

    const [classNames, setClassNames] = useState(
        "increase-shadow-on-hover routine-card"
    );

    return (
        <Stack
            // className="decrease-shadow-on-hover-2"
            spacing={5}
            alignItems="center"
            sx={{
                width: "97vw",
                background: "rgba(8, 12, 30, 1)",
                mt: "120px",
                py: "40px",
                px: "10px",
                borderRadius: "30px",
            }}>
            <Typography
                className="gradient-text-4"
                sx={{
                    fontSize: "80px",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    mb: "20px",
                }}>
                Routines
            </Typography>
            {chosenRoutine === "" ? (
                <Stack
                    sx={{
                        px: "30px",
                        py: "20px",
                        pb: "40px",
                        borderRadius: "30px",
                    }}>
                    <Stack
                        direction="row"
                        sx={{
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            gap: "80px",
                            flexWrap: "wrap",
                        }}>
                        {chosenRegimeData.routine.map((routine, index) => (
                            <Box
                                key={index}
                                sx={{
                                    borderRadius: "30px",
                                }}>
                                <Box
                                    className={classNames}
                                    sx={{
                                        display: "grid",
                                        width: "400px",
                                        height: "370px",
                                        borderRadius: "30px",
                                        p: "10px",
                                        background: "rgba(10, 18, 38, 1)",
                                        position: "relative",
                                    }}>
                                    <img
                                        src={routine.image}
                                        alt="image"
                                        style={{
                                            width: "100%",
                                            height: "70%",
                                            borderRadius: "30px",
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Stack
                                        alignItems="center"
                                        spacing={1}
                                        sx={{
                                            width: "100%",
                                            background: "rgba(10, 18, 38, 1)",
                                            position: "absolute",
                                            bottom: "20px",
                                            pt: "2px",
                                            borderRadius: "30px",
                                        }}>
                                        <Typography
                                            className="gradient-text-2"
                                            sx={{
                                                width: "100%",
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                textTransform: "capitalize",
                                                textAlign: "center",
                                                fontSize: "24px",
                                            }}>
                                            {routine.name}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                                            <Button
                                                size="large"
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                className="gradient-text-5"
                                                onClick={() => {
                                                    setClassNames("pressed-2");
                                                    console.log("pressed", index);
                                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                                        setClassNames("increase-shadow-on-hover");
                                                        showRoutineExercises(routine);
                                                    }, 300);
                                                }}>
                                                See Exercises in this Routine
                                            </Button>
                                        </Stack>
                                    </Stack>
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                        ))}
                    </Stack>
                    <Stack
                        direction="row"
                        className="datagrid-container"
                        sx={{
                            mt: "150px !important",
                            height: "fit-content",
                            width: "fit-content",
                            display: "grid",
                            placeItems: "center",
                            mx: "auto !important",
                        }}>
                        <DataGrid
                            onRowClick={(params, event) => {
                                console.log(params, event);
                                setHide((prev) => (prev === "hide" ? "" : ", hide"));
                            }}
                            // initialState={{
                            //  pagination: {
                            //      paginationModel: { pageSize: 5, page: 0 },
                            //  },
                            // }}
                            onCellEditStop={handleCellEditStop}
                            rows={rows}
                            columns={columns}
                            sx={{
                                color: "#fff",
                                height: "fit-content",
                            }}
                        />
                        <DeleteIcon
                            onClick={() => {}}
                            className={hide}
                            sx={{
                                width: "40px",
                                height: "40px",
                                color: "#ff3232",
                                ml: "10px",
                                cursor: "pointer",
                            }}
                        />
                    </Stack>
                </Stack>
            ) : (
                <ExercisesOfRoutine
                    routine={chosenRoutine}
                    addFunction={addWorkout}
                    removeFunction={removeWorkout}
                    setChosenRoutine={setChosenRoutine}
                    handleCellEditStop={handleCellEditStop}
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide={hide}
                    setHide={setHide}
                />
            )}
        </Stack>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a certain class to change once the card is clicked, you could try one of this two aproaces:

1-Set a pseudoselector which imitates the onclick event to your classes:
[Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

2- create a function for the onclick event of each card,

```
 onClick={(e)=>addAnimationClass(e)}

const addAnimationClass = event => event.target.classList.add('your-animation-className');
```

This is only for adding but then if you want to click on another box and get the previously clicked with its classes restored you could get an aproach as this example:

```
function BoxList() {
  const [selectedBox, setSelectedBox] = useState(null);

  const handleBoxClick = (boxId) => {
    setSelectedBox(boxId);
  };

  const boxData = [
    { id: 1, color: 'red' },
    { id: 2, color: 'blue' },
    { id: 3, color: 'green' },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {boxData.map((box) => (
        <div
          key={box.id}
          className={`box ${selectedBox === box.id ? 'your-animation-className' : ''}`}
          style={{ backgroundColor: box.color }}
          onClick={() => handleBoxClick(box.id)}
        ></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But can you tell me what was wrong with the method I previously used? And also why it works in some cases, and not for others.