# Display image at full page

Tags: html, css

I want to apply CSS code when the image is clicked and make it cover the whole page, even if the page is scrolled, without going to the top of the page. I mean the image should be displayed in its current position and cover the whole page.

I have used this code, but it only displays the image within the dialog. I want the entire page to be displayed by adding the following CSS properties:

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  z-index: 9999;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: show us what you have done then we can help you from there

Comment: I have used this code, but it only displays the image within the dialog. I want the entire page to be displayed by adding the following CSS properties

Comment: What "dialog"? You are talking about things only you know about so far here. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I mean dialog box or modal

Comment: Yes we know what you mean, however, we need to understand the code for your dialog box in order to help you. width 100% will only apply to the container the image is in. You may want to try `100vw` `100vh` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think this is possible without javascript. If it is possible, please correct me. Since, to my knowledge, CSS does not support click listeners. If you really want to imitate this behavior in CSS, you could read this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css). But I would recommend you to stick with JS.

However, I have created a small CodePen here that should meet your requirements. As long as I have understood your question correctly.

The images I used can't be displayed in complete fullscreen though, try this with the images you want to use.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.click-to-fullscreen');
const fullscreenOverlay = document.querySelector('.fullscreen-overlay');
const fullscreenImage = fullscreenOverlay.querySelector('.fullscreen-image');

images.forEach((image, index) => {
    image.addEventListener('click', () => {
        fullscreenImage.src = image.src;
        fullscreenOverlay.style.display = 'flex';
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    });
});

fullscreenOverlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fullscreenOverlay.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
});
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-gallery img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
}

.fullscreen-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.fullscreen-image {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/25/200/300" alt="Image 1" class="click-to-fullscreen">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/70/200/300" alt="Image 2" class="click-to-fullscreen">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/125/200/300" alt="Image 3" class="click-to-fullscreen">
</div>
<div class="fullscreen-overlay">
  <img src="" alt="Selected Image" class="fullscreen-image">
</div>
```

Additionally heres the [codepen](https://codepen.io/schtucks/pen/ZEVxwzj).

Comment: I don't access to HTML code. I only can to inject CSS and Java Script and apply to whole page not  in "modal"

Comment: I'll need more information about your use case. I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish ... maybe try using `deepl.com` to translate your question to english.

Comment: in my page exist a button that when click it open a modal and show image. that image on modal and it has small size. OK? alright. now I want to apply CSS code when the image is clicked and make it cover the whole page

Comment: But you can only inject css code?

Comment: No ... I can Inject CSS and java script or Jquery ... But my problem is CSS . What I said above was the complete scenario @stax

Comment: You have to at least provide me with your code or something like that so i can look into it in detail. Try creating a codepen or some reproducable example ... otherwise i won't be able to help you.