# making an element visible by clicking another one , using html and css

Tags: html, css

How can I make `.choices__items` visible until next click is occured?
It didn't work by setting transition to the parent. I want that class to be visible till the user clicks anywhere else.

```css
.choices__items {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.choices:active .choices__items {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
  <span>movies</span>
  <div class="choices__items">
    <div>
      <a>all</a>
      <a>films</a>
      <a>series</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

Comment: thats also what i meant ,by the way i dont know anything about js and its functions im just trying to do my best with css :).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make `.choices__items` visible until next click is occured? It didn't work by setting transition to the parent.

No, it wouldn't.  CSS transitions *animate* changes to specified CSS properties of the elements they are assigned to.  They do not *produce* changes to that element's properties, much less to any other element's.

The primary challenge here is that divs do not automatically acquire or maintain state in response to clicks within.  There is no sense of an "active" div like there is of an `<input>` element.  You need to introduce something that will hold that state for you.

A comment on the question links to a suggestion that boils down to using a checkbox for maintaining that state, which indeed seems apropos.  And you don't need the checkbox to be displayed, because if you link a label to it then clicking on the label has the same effect as clicking on the checkbox.  For example:

```css
input.is_active {
  display: none;
}

.choices__items {
  visibility: hidden;
}

:checked + .choices__items {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
  <span>movies</span>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="is_active"></input>
    <div class="choices__items">
      <div>
        <a>all</a>
        <a>films</a>
        <a>series</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great expansion on a already appropriate answer in the "Duplicate" I proposed.  The hidden checkbox is a great work around.