Wacky UI challenge…sans Javascript if possible
Hello Stack Overflowers,
Currently desktop only (I still have to build out element interpolations).
I'm totally blocked on how to achieve this aspect of my layout. I'd like the bullet to transition to a menu when clicked (comp): You'll observe that h1's children take display: inline-block to take advantage of the writing-mode default (horizontal-tb). The monospaced font makes the grid like effect possible, without the need for grid or flex-wrap: flex. I know it's possible with <dialog> but that requires JavaScript and I need this to work without JavaScript. Maybe I could use an inline <label><input type="checkbox" /> </label> instead of the <a>? The nav needn't be an <ul><li>…it could be <span><br> for example. I'm just stuck on how to achieve this without breaking the inline elements' flow. 


*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Chivo Mono", monospace;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 0.725;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

h1>* {
  display: inline-block;
}

h1>* {
  font-weight: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0.045cap 0 0.045cap;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  transition: font-weight 2s, rotate 2.5s, scale 1.5s;
}

b:hover {
  transition: font-weight 560ms, rotate 440ms, scale 420ms;
  font-weight: 100;
  rotate: 270deg;
  scale: 65%;
}

a {
  /* background-color: orangered;
            border-radius: 10px; */
  color: orangered;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: transform 600ms;
}

a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}

nav {
  display: none;
  /* display: grid; */
  /* place-content: center; */
}

.cover {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-block-size: 100vh;
}

.cover>h1 {
  margin-block: auto;
}
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Chivo+Mono:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>
  <b>A</b><b>b</b><b>a</b><b>l</b><b>o</b><b>n</b><b>e</b><a href="#menu">&bull;</a><b>H</b><b>a</b><b>b</b><b>i</b><b>t</b><b>a</b><b>t</b>
</h1>

<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>




Without JavaScript, your best bet is probably the checkbox hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32721572/14776809
